# How to Get More Information with UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception

I am using [Uncaught Exception Handler](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html). Is there a way that I can use to get the stack traces when after `rethrow`? And gather more information about the back traces? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the development environment, there is one more way:

- Go to break point section in the left pane of Xcode.
- Find '+' button, in the below tab. Click it.
- Select "Add Exception Breakpoint".
- A dialogue will appear. Select check box for "exception Breakpoint"
- Set Exception to "All".
- Set On Throw for Break.

Run the application. When it will hit an unhanded exception (apart from EXC_BAD_ACCESS), executing process will be stopped at that statement.

Comment: Thanks! I know that way but I will use it log the crash into the server to analyze it. The crash will be coming from the users of the app/game.